# Css positioning svg images as background

Tags: css, svg, styled-components, react-tsx

I have multiple Svgs like this one:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path fill="#FF0066" d="M56.2,-36.9C66.8,-14.2,65,11.2,53.6,31.9C42.2,52.6,21.1,68.7,-3.8,70.8C-28.6,73,-57.2,61.3,-64.8,42.8C-72.4,24.3,-59,-1,-44.7,-25.9C-30.4,-50.8,-15.2,-75.3,3.8,-77.5C22.8,-79.7,45.7,-59.6,56.2,-36.9Z" transform="translate(100 100)" />
</svg>
```

I have two questions:

I'm working in **react TS** with styled-components library. I'm new to using this css library and I can't figure out how would be the standard way of styling an svg tag.

**1.** What I have thought is making a component and pass in props for the positioning, like this:

```
export interface BlobProps {
    width: string;
    top: string;
    right: string;
  }

const Blob = styled.svg<BlobProps>`
    position: absolute;
    top: ${ (p:BlobProps) => p.top };
    right: ${ (p:BlobProps) => p.right }; };
    z-index:-1;
    width: ${ (p:BlobProps) => `calc(${p.width} - 10rem)` };
`;
```

It does the job but I'm not sure how clean is this.

**2.** On other note: I want the blobs to maintain their positions but decrese their size as the screen get smaller.
Right now I adjust the blob sizes relative to the view width but either way they end up disappearing on mobile screen sizes.

A visual representation of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the images are placed as background in CSS they can be scales and moved around according to the relative size of the viewport. An element can have [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds) -- the values for each image are separated by commas in the property.

In this example the first image will always have the size of 40% and will always be positioned relative to .5em from the top and aligning to the right.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KICAgPHBhdGggb3BhY2l0eT0iLjUiIGZpbGw9InRvbWF0byIgZD0iTTU2LjIsLTM2LjlDNjYuOCwtMTQuMiw2NSwxMS4yLDUzLjYsMzEuOUM0Mi4yLDUyLjYsMjEuMSw2OC43LC0zLjgsNzAuOEMtMjguNiw3MywtNTcuMiw2MS4zLC02NC44LDQyLjhDLTcyLjQsMjQuMywtNTksLTEsLTQ0LjcsLTI1LjlDLTMwLjQsLTUwLjgsLTE1LjIsLTc1LjMsMy44LC03Ny41QzIyLjgsLTc5LjcsNDUuNywtNTkuNiw1Ni4yLC0zNi45WiIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoMTAwIDEwMCkiIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPgo='),
    url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KICAgPHBhdGggb3BhY2l0eT0iLjUiIGZpbGw9IlNsYXRlQmx1ZSIgZD0iTTU2LjIsLTM2LjlDNjYuOCwtMTQuMiw2NSwxMS4yLDUzLjYsMzEuOUM0Mi4yLDUyLjYsMjEuMSw2OC43LC0zLjgsNzAuOEMtMjguNiw3MywtNTcuMiw2MS4zLC02NC44LDQyLjhDLTcyLjQsMjQuMywtNTksLTEsLTQ0LjcsLTI1LjlDLTMwLjQsLTUwLjgsLTE1LjIsLTc1LjMsMy44LC03Ny41QzIyLjgsLTc5LjcsNDUuNywtNTkuNiw1Ni4yLC0zNi45WiIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoMTAwIDEwMCkiIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPgo='),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KICAgPHBhdGggb3BhY2l0eT0iLjUiIGZpbGw9IlNwcmluZ0dyZWVuIiBkPSJNNTYuMiwtMzYuOUM2Ni44LC0xNC4yLDY1LDExLjIsNTMuNiwzMS45QzQyLjIsNTIuNiwyMS4xLDY4LjcsLTMuOCw3MC44Qy0yOC42LDczLC01Ny4yLDYxLjMsLTY0LjgsNDIuOEMtNzIuNCwyNC4zLC01OSwtMSwtNDQuNywtMjUuOUMtMzAuNCwtNTAuOCwtMTUuMiwtNzUuMywzLjgsLTc3LjVDMjIuOCwtNzkuNyw0NS43LC01OS42LDU2LjIsLTM2LjlaIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSgxMDAgMTAwKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg==');
  background-position: top .5em right, left 1em center, bottom -50vh center;
  background-size: 40%, 50%, 80%;
  background-attachment: local, scroll, fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>

<h2>Other stuff</h2>
```